# key not found for dict generated using sympy in julia

Tags: dictionary, julia, sympy

I am trying to access a value in a dictionary, but I keep getting the error "key [entry] isn't found." Here is a MWE:

`using sympy`

`sympy.eye(3).eigenvals()[1]`

gives "key 1 not found."

I'm very new to Julia, so I have no idea what could be going wrong.

Comment: Did you look at `sympy.eye(3).eigenvals()` by itself?  In Python this is a `dict`, with integer `1` as valid key.  But `dict` indexing julia might be different.

Comment: It is a dict, and its entry is `1 => 3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python the ordinary int `1` can be used interchangeably with SymPy's symbolic `S.One` as a dict key. However in the Julia dict those are not equivalent. You need to use the symbolic `S.One` explicitly:

```
julia> sympy.eye(3).eigenvals()[sympy.S.One]
3
```

Alternatively you can just extract the values into a list:

```
julia> d = sympy.eye(3).eigenvals()
Dict{Any, Any} with 1 entry:
  1 => 3

julia> collect(values(d))
1-element Vector{Any}:
 3

julia> collect(values(d))[1]  # 1 is the index of 1st element
3
```

Probably in your actual problem you should use something like `pairs` rather than `values`.

You can also ask SymPy's `eigenvals` method to return a list of all eigenvalues including repeats:

```
julia> sympy.eye(3).eigenvals(multiple=True)
3-element Vector{Sym}:
 1
 1
 1
```

Comment: What if I want to examine the key -1? EDIT: Nevermind. I figured it out!